# How to include elements of an array in another array?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

So for example I have a MAIN array with all the information I need:

```
  $scope.songs = [
    { title: 'Reggae',  url:"#/app/mworkouts", id: 1 },
    { title: 'Chill',   url:"#/app/browse",    id: 2 },
    { title: 'Dubstep', url:"#/app/search",    id: 3 },
    { title: 'Indie',   url:"#/app/search",    id: 4 },
    { title: 'Rap',     url:"#/app/mworkouts", id: 5 },
    { title: 'Cowbell', url:"#/app/mworkouts", id: 6 }
  ];
```

I want to put only certain objects into another array without typing in each of the objects so the end result will look like

```
  $scope.array1 = [
    { title: 'Reggae', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 1 },
    { title: 'Cowbell', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 6 }
  ];
```

I have tried this with no luck:

```
  $scope.array1 = [
    { $scope.songs[1] },
    { $scope.songs[6] }
  ];
```

I will have to do a bunch of these so typing in each object would take forever, is there any faster way to do this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `$scope.array1 = [
     $scope.songs[1] ,
     $scope.songs[6]
  ];`

Comment: Awesome! It's hard not knowing the correct syntax...thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
$scope.array1 = $scope.songs.filter(function (song) {
  return (song.title == "Reggae" || song.title == "Cowbell");
});
```

Here, the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function will give you a filtered new array to be replaced for the original scope value.

[image: console]

Or in simple way, using the array indices, you can use:

```
$scope.array1 = [ $scope.songs[0] , $scope.songs[5] ];
```

Comment: Keeping things simple and sexy, is there a way I could change some information in the object but keep all the other information the same? For Example, change just the id:1 to id:45 while still keeping title and url the same.

Comment: @MehdiN Yes, you can do it.. Just add `song.id += 44;` before the return statement. LoL. Might have undesirable effects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the braces since it's already an object. Although the array index starts from `0` so change index value based on `0`.

```
$scope.array1 = [ 
   $scope.songs[0] ,
   $scope.songs[5] 
];
```